# PHP script timing out/not running to completion

Tags: php, timeout

Part of a project I'm working on means running lots of benchmarks on cloud instances. To make it easier on myself, I want to make them runnable via the web and get the output printed straight to the browser window.

This seems to work fine, however, the script 'stops' after about 10 minutes of run time (i.e. the browser stops loading) - less than halfway through my benchmark, and I have no idea why. SSHing into the server and calling `top` shows that the process is stopping as well - but it will complete if I call `./runscript.sh` from the command line.

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(1);

header("Content-type: text/plain");


ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();

$old_path = getcwd();
chdir("UnixBench");
passthru("./runscript.sh");
chdir($old_path);
?>
```

In this instance, `runscript.sh` is simply

```
#!/bin/bash

./Run &
wait $!
```

Comment: it could also time out on web server or browser side

Comment: Hadn't considered browser timeout. I'll attempt to run it in IE (afaik 60min timeout) which could be an answer

Comment: anything running that long should have nothing to do with the browser, it should be run from the cli

Comment: No luck. Stopped at around the same time in IE.

Comment: @Dagon I realize it's unconventional but it's purely for my convenience. If I can make it work, is there really an issue?

Comment: run in background poll the db\file for results from the browser if required

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation, I changed the script to **emit spaces every few seconds**.

Comment: I actually get some output every 10-20 seconds while this is running